# Why does Rails controller not have an if statement to check if destroy was successful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I noticed that the default controller generated by rails has `if` statements in `create` and `update` but not in `destroy`

```
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

No if statement in case the destroy fails

```
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Here is the rest of the scaffolded controller.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.json
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Why does Rails controller not have an IF statement in destroy method by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `create` or `update`, there is a chance that the data will not match the requirements. For example, if you try to insert a nil value into a column with `NOT NULL`, or if a value isn't within a range specified by a Rails `validate` method.

In these instances, if we fail to *save the data*, we want to respond accordingly, such as with a new input form where the user can make corrections, etc. But if succeeds, we typically redirect to the `show` page.

When using `destroy`, on the other hand, we're normally removing a row from the database. Since this process doesn't include any validation, there's no (or, perhaps, very little) concern that things will go wrong. So in this situation, we don't need the if statement, and we can proceed without caution.

Comment: There might still be foreign key validations in the db, or `before_destroy`s in the model stopping the delete operation

Comment: You are right, there might be everything during the deletion of the record, but scaffold is a default template.

Comment: @Iceman Yes, that is correct, but I don't think the scaffold is accounting for those situations. The scaffold is just concerned with simple CRUD, and depends on the coder to alter it if anything more substantial is required.

Comment: @Yaniv Yes, I see your point even though I don't necessarily agree with it completely. But it would be interesting to know the real reason behind this decision, because if I remember correctly it has been virtually unchanged since ancient times, at least Rails 2.

Comment: mostly likely it is because of security reasons. So that you don't accidentally end up providing information to the attacker, as to why the certain record is not being deleted.
However, you can change it and handle the foreign key constraints keeping security in mind